# Formatting not working anywhere

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I have tried on many different browsers and computers to format my SO questions, but they always end up showing up as unformatted paragraph text, and someone else formats them. I indent by text four spaces for code, but it does not work.
Original edit screenshot:
[image: original edit screenchot]

Source of edit:
[image: source of edit]

Comment: Screenshot?????

Comment: Add an empty line between your regular text and your code. (I just checked one of your SO posts and that was the issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be an empty line between the last paragraph and your code block.

[image]

The above doesn't work, but this one will:

[image]

<sub>*Taken from your SO answer*</sub>